# The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to access my MSSQL database from another machine on the network.

The machine is not in a domain or anything. Just has an IP set. How can I enable my MSSQL database so it can be accessed from another machine?

I do **not** want to add the machine to the domain as the target clients don't *have* a domain. They just have collective group of machines (2 pcs) with IP addresses in the same subnet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'mirrored accounts'. If you run as a user local user 'foo' and connect to a machine that also has a local user 'foo' and the two have *identical* passwords on both machines, then NTLM will authenticate you successfully as the target machine 'foo' user. This is the typical deployment done in Workgroups or when crossing non-trusted domain boundaries. It is basically a hack, so don't abuse it. Usually one combines 'mirrored accounts' for the network authentication but runs locally as a 'correct user', see [`runas /netonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772672%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

There is an example on this on the ASP.Net authentication whitepaper [How To: Connect to SQL Server Using Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx#paght000008_mirroredaccounts), look at the Mirrored Accounts section of the document.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that popped into my mind was trying to connect with the ip address, and then using sql server authentication.

Comment: SQL Server authentication will work well, even connecting with the machine name !

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use a mirrored account, use the runas /netonly approach to access that network resource with a local user of that server